# Need to assign user selected sheet name to variable

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I would like to prompt the user to select a cell within a sheet to populate a value. I'm trying to use `Application.Input`, but it doesn't grab the name of the sheet that the cell was selected in....it keeps using the sheetname that was active when the macro is run.

I've search everywhere. Is there a way to assign the sheetname to a variable, along with the range of the cell selected by the user when prompted?

```
varCellContent = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Choose a sheet by clicking on any cell in it.", Type:=8)
strDestinationSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
MsgBox ("Sheet = " & strDestinationSheetName)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim varCellContent As Range
    Dim strDestinationSheetName As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Set varCellContent = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Choose a sheet by clicking on any cell in it.", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not varCellContent Is Nothing Then
        strDestinationSheetName = varCellContent.Parent.Name

        MsgBox ("Sheet = " & strDestinationSheetName)
    End If
End Sub
```